# Is it true that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i$, where $a_i\in \Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it true that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ where $a_i\in \Bbb R$ for $i=1,...n$.

I think it is true since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} C =C$, where $C=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i$.

---

I wanted to use Cauchy's inequality in a proof and I was not sure if I could use this double summation.
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_i^2 \geq \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right)^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_k^2,$$
then I wanted to add a summation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}$ to the right-hand side
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right)^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_k^2\geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_ic_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_ic_i.$$

Can I do that?

---

Ok, I can't.

Comment: It's not clear what your expression is even supposed to mean. Can you write it out explicitly for, say $n=2, a_1=1, a_2=2$?

Comment: It's false, you would need to redifine $a_i$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} C =nC$, not $C$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Do I need to assign number to each $a_i$? I think the information $a_i\in \Bbb R$ is enough.

Comment: "Need to"? No. Doing so, however, makes it more concrete, and might make you realize how your use of $i$ as the index in both sums is problematic.

Comment: According to comments on an answer below, using "i" for both sums is just fine, but I still say it's confusing and wise to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We have
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^na_i}&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\right)\\
> &=\left(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\right)\sum_{i=1}^n1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n\sum_{i=1}^na_i}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** A preferable notation for this situation is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\color{blue}{j=1}}^{\color{blue}{n}}\sum_{i=1}^na_i=n\sum_{i=1}^na_i
\end{align*}

Comment: Why doesn't the $i$ in the outer sum affect the $i$ in your inner sum?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs because the inner sum does not depend on the outer $i$. Once the inner sum is evaluated, it is a fixed number independent of any index, so it's like just adding a constant

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: The scope of $i$ of the outer sum does not affect the inner sum. We are in the same situation as in $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^na_i$.

Comment: @AndreaL.: Thanks for your comment, Andrea. (+1)

Comment: Hrm. I see what you mean, but it seems to me to be horribly sloppy notation.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: I agree. This situation should only be for case studies not within real applications.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not true since

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^n1=n,
\end{equation*}

unless $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=0$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true, generally speaking. As Martin's comment points out:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^na_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nC=nC=n\sum_{i=1}^na_i
$$
so, no. But, for instance, if $a_i=0\;\forall i$ then the equality you posted will be true. You can ask whether there are sequences $\{a\}_n$ such that your equality is true, or maybe prove that there is no possible $\{a\}_n$ (with at least one nonzero element) that satisfies your above equation.